# No logro hacer funcionar un Radio Group con MUI y Formik

Tags: nextjs, radiogroup, styled-components, mui

Tengo un formulario con `useFormik` en `Next 13`, y todo funciona bien excepto un `radio button`, visualmente no muestra cambios al hacer click en los checkbox.

Mi componente inicial, hecho con `styled components`:

```
   const handleRadioButtons = e => {
      console.log("A handle radio button llega: ", e.target.value);
      formik.values.active = e.target.value === "true";
      console.log("Active? ", formik.values.active);
   };

    <FormInput>
      <StyledRadio
        align="end"
        checkedLabel="Active"
        label="Active Connection"
        name="active"
        unCheckedLabel="Inactive"
        value={formik.values.active}
        onChange={e => handleRadioButtons(e)}
      />
    </FormInput>
```

Finalmente mi componente `Styled Radio`

```
const StyledRadioComponent = ({
  className,
  checkedLabel,
  unCheckedLabel,
  onChange,
  id,
  label,
  name,
  value,
  size,
}) => (
  <FormControl
    className={className || "radio-group"}
    id={id}
  >
    <FormLabel id={`radio-buttons-group-${label ? label : "label"}`}>{label || "Please select an option"}</FormLabel>
    <RadioGroup
      aria-labelledby={`radio-buttons-group-${label ? label : "label"}`}
      defaultValue={value}
      name={name || "radio-buttons-group"}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    >
      <FormControlLabel
        value
        checked={value === true}
        control={<Radio size={size || "large"} />}
        label={checkedLabel || "On"}
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        checked={value === false}
        control={<Radio size={size || "large"} />}
        label={unCheckedLabel || "Off"}
        value={false}
      />
    </RadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
);

StyledRadioComponent.propTypes = propTypes;

export default StyledRadio;
```

Estoy intentando hacer que al cambiar el checkbox, cambie el valor de `formik.values.active`, yo veo que cuando se carga la app está en `true`, hago click en false y el valor cambia en el componente, pero no se visualiza el cambio en los checkbox.

A mi funcion `handleRadioButtons` llegan los valores correctos, setea `formik.values.active` correctamente pero no se ve el cambio en el checkbox.

Estoy un poco perdido con `value`, `checkedValue`  y el hecho de que por momentos `true` y `false` son convertidos a `string` por el componente de MUI. Alguna recomendacion?

Comment: probaste a poner en los 2 formcontrollabel `checked={value === "true"} value="true"` y el otro igual pero con false?

Comment: @Suso si, probe eso, es raro: Solo funciona en el primer intento. Es decir, la app se carga con ese valor en true, por ende esta seleccionado el checkbox en ``active``. Si lo pongo en ``false`` el checkbox cambia, pero si ahora lo pongo en ``true`` ya no cambia (no cambia el checkbox, el valor de ``formik.values.active`` sí cambia

Comment: @Suso, de hecho pasa algo rarisimo. Si yo dejo que la pagina se cargue por completo, no anda esto ultimo que hablamos. Si en cambio yo le doy click al checkbox false antes que se termine de cargar todo, funciona (solo la primera vez). Creo que tengo algun problema de sincronia, ya que el componente padre manda funciones y props al ``styled component``, este deberia devolver un valor al padre, que deberia ejecutar cambios (Esto lo veo bien) y que luego deben volver a mnodificar la vista del ``styled component``. Sospecho que el problema esta en este ultimo cambio pero no lo veo.

Comment: Pues lo unico que se me ocurre y viendo la documentacion de MUI, es que elimines la propiedad checked, ya que esa solo se usa cuando el componente Radio no va envuelto en un RadioGroup

Comment: @Suso ya lo arregle, el problema es la forma en la que modifico el ``state`` de ``useFormik``, lo hago directamente ``formik.values.active = e.target.value === "true";`` y la forma correcta es ``formik.setFieldValue("active", e.target.value)``.